# Overflow hidden is not working in iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ipad

I have been trying to disable the scroll on body when modal pop up appears.I added body overflow hidden when i open the modal pop up and i will set it to default state when i close the pop up.this technique works well in all desktop browsers but not in mobile devices.To fix the issue in iPod/iPhone i added

```
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

but it does not work in iPad.
my code

```
function toggleMenu() {
if (!toggle) {
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
}else{
$("body").css("overflow", "");
}
toggle = !toggle;
```

I have tried many solution suggested in stack overflow but no luck.
Note:Position fixed also tried but no luck.
it works well all the other devices except iPod.Donot know how to solve please somebody help me to fix issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Try setting a `max-height: 100vh` to your body and a `height: 100vh` to your `<html>`. But since you don't have a minimal verifyable example, this is as good as a random guess.

Comment: Also, to remove all possible cases when background can be scrolled you can hide container that give the body bigger height. Like set display: none;

Answer (score 0):

try this

IPad in portrait & landscape

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { 
body{overflow:hidden;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
body.modal-open {
    overflow: hidden;
    position:fixed;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This solution have a side effect of scrolling to the top.

If you want to make the scroll position persist after closing modal, you should add more handling codes like below.

```
var scrollPosition;

function onOpenModal(){
    scrollPosition = $('body').scrollTop();
    $('body').css("position", "fixed");
};

function onCloseModal(){
    $('body').css("position", "static");
    $('body').animate({"scrollTop": scrollPosition}, 0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `{}` when changing css arguments Change:

```
$("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

To:

```
$("body").css({
   "overflow" : "hidden"
});
```